# Views containing calculated values (category totals) not shown in XPages

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I was reading through [a few active SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905962/data-table-to-show-only-category-totals) and I came across this one that reminded me of a question that I have had for a while.

In a few applications that I have done, there came a point when I had to use a view that uses category totals to display some easy to read values, such as cost, or counts, or whatever.  Up until now, I have always had to find workarounds for these totals because I could not get them to show up in the dynamicViewPanels, or anything else of the like.  My solutions have always been, (as David Leedy suggests in the linked question) static HTML tables displaying the counts with the category, View Navigators which display the information in repeaters, and building complex dialogs which allow the user to pick certain information to get a calculation table with the appropriate values and formulas etc.

My question is, did I overlook something in the controls that actually allow these column totals to show up in the existing view panel controls?

**EDIT**
Just for the sake of clarity, I am not talking about a column with a calculated value, but really the totals for categories.

Comment: My first thought would be to use view navigators. I have done it by calculating the values in SSJS, but letting the view do it for you is better.

Comment: i have been using view navigators and the other methods mentioned in the question.  My primary question is whether you can indeed "let the view do it for you".  Up until now, I could never get them to automatically show up.

Comment: Based on your edit, I would say that yes, view navigators would be the way to go.  I haven't had to do that yet, but I bet you will get an answer soon from someone who has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [ready baked function](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=aggregate-categorized-views-into-json-for-consumption-in-e.g-d3js) that uses a ViewNavigator to get to values from category totals. That just might do the trick for you.